# Best way to remove anchors from concrete?

Tags: concrete, screws, removal, anchor

The people we purchased our home from put up a wall in the 3 car garage between the 1st and 2nd space, but never finished it and I am now looking to remove the entire wall.

[image: half finished wall in garage]

There are several anchors in the concrete that I will need to remove that look like this:

[image: concrete anchors]

[image: concrete anchors]

I am relatively new to owning a home and am not exactly sure of the best way to extract them. What tools or methods can I use to remove the anchors without too much hassle?

Once removed how would I go about repairing the concrete easily?

Thank you for your responses and advice!

Comment: Those are ramset (powder actuated tool - a "nailgun" in the most gunlike sense of the word) anchors. I suspect you'll just have to grind the heads off and leave the shanks in the concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most anchors don't come out of concrete.  You have two choices.  If you need to keep the look (little chipping) hit it with an angle grinder plus diamond blade.  If you are putting something over these, hammer and sharp chisel works really fast.

Comment: Eww - diamond blade on steel is a very expensive way to make diamond blade into formerly diamond blade, unless it's aggressively cooled (ie, water-flooded.) Diamonds are carbon, steel loves carbon, and steel at a certain temperature easily reached in grinding will take carbon from diamond tooling. Grind the steel parts of these anchors with a nice cheap cutoff disk made for grinding steel, not a diamond blade made for cutting concrete or ceramics.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - good call.  I have at least 10 old diamond blades I used for tile that I would use for something like this.  Definitely not starting out with a new diamond blade.